# asp.net boton funciona en el segundo click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un botón en asp.net el cual hace una acción de forma correcta, adicionalmente he creado una función en javascript para que muestre un mensaje de confirmación.

El problema ocurre debido a que el botón solo funciona cuándo es pulsado por segunda vez.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function mensaje() {
        var btn = $('#<%=btn_distribuir.ClientID %>').attr('name');
        abcbpo.ConfigConfirmacion('confirmacion', 'spanConfirmacion', '¿Estás seguro registrar la operación?', btn);});
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btn_distribuir" runat="server" OnClientClick="$('#confirmacion').dialog('open'); return false;" Text="Confirmar Distribución Facturas" Width="250px" />
```

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btn_distribuir" runat="server"                                           OnClientClick="$('#confirmacion').dialog('open'); return false;" Text="Confirmar Distribución Facturas" Width="250px" />

Comment: Hola Leandro, ante todo muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Te comento que sigo teniendo el problema. lo raro es que uso esta misma función en otros modulos del proyecto y me funciona perfectamente. en cuanto a abcbpo.ConfigConfirmacion() el abcbpo es un archivo con extension .js en el proyecto y ConfigConfirmacion() detalla la siguiente funcion:

Comment: ConfigConfirmacion: function (selectorDiv, selectorSpan, mensaje, ctrlToPostBack) {
        $('#' + selectorSpan).html(mensaje);
        $('#' + selectorDiv).dialog({
            title: 'ABC',
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Aceptar": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    __doPostBack(ctrlToPostBack, '');
                },
                "Cancelar": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

Comment: En el modulo donde tengo el problema, antes de hacer click en el boton en cuestion, uso otros botones, uno de ellos me permite cargar informacion de un gridview a otro y otro boton donde seleccionar informacion de dropdownlistbox, para por ultimo dar click en el boton distribuir el cual en el primer click no hace nada y en el segundo click se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: He leido informacion que relacionada al problema el cual dice que al ejecutarse el boton por primera vez lo hace con ID incorrecto y al hacer la segunda vez lo hacer con el ID correcto, aun asi no logro dar con la solucion....

Answer (score 1):

en el OnClientClick veo que defines un `.dialog('open');`, pero no veo que en ningun momento invoques a la funcion `mensaje()` ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mensaje(ctrl) 
    {
        //$('#confirmacion').dialog('open');

        var btn = $(ctrl).attr('name');
        abcbpo.ConfigConfirmacion('confirmacion', 'spanConfirmacion', '¿Estás seguro registrar la operación?', btn);}

        return false;
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btn_distribuir" runat="server" OnClientClick="return mensaje(this);" Text="Confirmar Distribución Facturas" Width="250px" />
```

como veras la funcion no se define dentro de $() de jquery alli solo se adjuntan eventos
Lo que no tenia claro es que seria este `abcbpo.ConfigConfirmacion()` pero imagine que despues de aceptado el dialogo realizaria el post del boton, aunque recuerda que si usas el `.dialog('open');` vas a tener que usar `__dopostBack()` para lanzar el evento del boton desde javascript